# Passing parameter to component live update in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [geosuggest](http://ubilabs.github.io/react-geosuggest/) and
Im attempting to succinctly pass my state in React but am having errors come up.

Here is my [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lukecurtis/7urk2xhj/)
I have the following in my default class:

```
{!this.state.isHidden && <Address state={this.state} />}
```

Which renders out:

```
class Address extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-2">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-borders" required name="address_line_one" defaultValue={this.props.state.address_line_one} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-2"> 
                    <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-borders" required name="address_suburb" defaultValue={this.props.state.address_suburb} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-2"> 
                    <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-borders" required name="address_city" defaultValue={this.props.state.address_city} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-2"> 
                    <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-borders" required name="address_postcode" defaultValue={this.props.state.address_postcode} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Essentially what happens is on bind the values for each address is put into a variable depending on when you click on a 'suggested result' and when you click on 'Can't find your address?' it opens the the input and you can type the answer yourself.

However if I press 'can't find your address' and then attempt to use the geosuggest module, it doesn't populate the fields with the new variables I made when i click a suggested location.

Sorry im super new to react here im just wondering if i've binded my state wrong or something?

Comment: did you use chrome debugger to check state?

Comment: Yeah the state updates but not the values in the input boxes, it's as if I need to re-render the input boxes if i select a new location

Comment: it seems that you are not specifying what state is in your if statement. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Do you mean the toggleHidden state?

Comment: {!this.state.isHidden && <Address state={this.state} />}

Comment: you need to make your props avilable outside of your class. have you tried looking into using proptypes?